# Configuring distcc for makefiles

Tags: makefile, cmake, distcc

I am testing [distcc](https://distcc.github.io/faq.html) and I found this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@konrad.wilhelm.kleine/3-tips-to-make-your-cxx-projects-compile-5-times-faster-3847eee9d55c) very easy to follow, I should say that I am able to compile `llvm` using `CMake + Ninja` and `CMake + Makefiles` using `distcc` and `docker` with no problems. Since I am particularly interested in Makefiles, I looked at the files produced by `CMake + Ninja` and all I saw was that `distcc` is added as a prefix to the compiler (e.g. `distcc /usr/bin/gcc`). So I thought that if I create a [small project](https://github.com/berthin/distcc-makefiles) using only Makefiles I could possibly add `distcc` and things will magically work. Well, looks like I am missing something because all I get is:

```
$ ./mk.sh image

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles'
Compiling Lib/Print.c
Compiling Boot/Main.c
distcc[16644] ERROR: compile Boot/Main.c on 172.17.0.2/1 failed
distcc[16644] (dcc_build_somewhere) Warning: remote compilation of 'Boot/Main.c' failed, retrying locally
distcc[16644] Warning: failed to distribute Boot/Main.c to 172.17.0.2/1, running locally instead
distcc[16644] (dcc_please_send_email_after_investigation) Warning: remote compilation of 'Boot/Main.c' failed, retried locally and got a different result.
distcc[16643] ERROR: compile Lib/Print.c on 172.17.0.2/1 failed
distcc[16643] (dcc_build_somewhere) Warning: remote compilation of 'Lib/Print.c' failed, retrying locally
distcc[16643] Warning: failed to distribute Lib/Print.c to 172.17.0.2/1, running locally instead
distcc[16643] (dcc_please_send_email_after_investigation) Warning: remote compilation of 'Lib/Print.c' failed, retried locally and got a different result.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles'
```

By running the `llvm` example I discarded all `docker` connection and `distcc` configuration issues, I tried to search for any ideas/examples on the internet but most of the people use `CMake` which is not my case. Suggestions are welcome, I based my demo project on a real project I am working on, so that's how basically the `Makefile` look like.

I don't know what I am missing...

**Versions**:

Just for reference:

```
$ distcc --version
distcc 3.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  (protocols 1, 2 and 3) (default port 3632)
  built Oct 19 2017 11:05:18
Copyright (C) 2002, 2003, 2004 by Martin Pool.
Includes miniLZO (C) 1996-2002 by Markus Franz Xaver Johannes Oberhumer.
Portions Copyright (C) 2007-2008 Google.
```

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling debug messages (with `$ export DISTCC_VERBOSE=1`), I found that `distcc` actually compiles in the server but the compilation fails and that's why it retries locally.

It fails because I am using external files to keep additional options (see [*gcc @file*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)) and `distcc` doesnt interpret that as a file but rather as a string basically. That's why the compilation fails and `distcc` fallsback.

### Log inspection

For reference, the `distcc` log looks like the following (divided into sections for further explanation):

```
... {{ SECTION A }}
distcc[13039] (dcc_spawn_child) forking to execute: gcc -std=c99 -Wall @_out/Release/Boot/Main.o.via -E /home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles/Boot/Main.c
distcc[13040] (dcc_get_hostlist) read hosts from environment
distcc[13040] (dcc_parse_hosts) found tcp token "172.17.0.2/1"
distcc[13039] (dcc_spawn_child) child started as pid13041

... {{ SECTION B }}

distcc[13039] (dcc_strip_local_args) result: gcc -std=c99 -Wall @_out/Release/Boot/Main.o.via -c /home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles/Boot/Main.c -o _out/Release/Boot/Main.o
distcc[13039] exec on 172.17.0.2/1: gcc -std=c99 -Wall @_out/Release/Boot/Main.o.via -c /home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles/Boot/Main.c -o _out/Release/Boot/Main.o
distcc[13039] (dcc_note_state) note state 2, file "Main.c", host "172.17.0.2"
distcc[13039] (dcc_connect_by_name) connecting to 172.17.0.2 port 3632
distcc[13041] (dcc_new_pgrp) entered process group
distcc[13041] (dcc_increment_safeguard) setting safeguard: _DISTCC_SAFEGUARD=1
distcc[13039] (dcc_connect_by_addr) started connecting to 172.17.0.2:3632

... {{ SECTION C }}

distcc[13039] (dcc_select_for_write) select for write on fd6
distcc[13039] (dcc_note_state) note state 4, file "(NULL)", host "(NULL)"
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send DIST00000001
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGC00000008
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGV00000003
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_string) send string 'gcc'
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGV00000008
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_string) send string '-std=c99'
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGV00000005
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_string) send string '-Wall'
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGV0000001d
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_string) send string '@_out/Release/Boot/Main.o.via'
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGV00000002
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_string) send string '-c'
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGV0000002f
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_string) send string '/home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles/Boot/Main.c'
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGV00000002
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_string) send string '-o'
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGV00000018
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_string) send string '_out/Release/Boot/Main.o'
distcc[13039] (dcc_note_state) note state 3, file "(NULL)", host "(NULL)"
distcc[13039] (dcc_collect_child) cpp child 13041 terminated with status 0
distcc[13039] (dcc_collect_child) cpp times: user 0.000000s, system 0.000000s, 0 minflt, 0 majflt
distcc[13039] cpp /home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles/Boot/Main.c on localhost completed ok

... {{ SECTION D }}

distcc[13039] (dcc_unlock) release lock fd4
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_file) send 14682 byte file /tmp/distcc_cd4d9216.i with token DOTI and compression 69
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send DOTI0000395a
distcc[13039] (dcc_compile_remote) client finished sending request to server
distcc[13039] (dcc_note_state) note state 5, file "(NULL)", host "172.17.0.2"
distcc[13039] (dcc_select_for_read) select for read on fd6 for 300s
distcc[13039] (dcc_r_token_int) got DONE00000001
distcc[13039] (dcc_note_state) note state 6, file "(NULL)", host "(NULL)"
distcc[13039] (dcc_r_token_int) got STAT00000100
distcc[13039] (dcc_r_token_int) got SERR00000044
distcc[13039] (dcc_r_file) received 68 bytes to file /tmp/distcc_server_stderr_cd009216.txt
distcc[13039] (dcc_r_token_int) got SOUT00000000
distcc[13039] (dcc_r_token_int) got DOTO00000000

... {{ SECTION E }}

distcc[13039] 14682 bytes from /home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles/Boot/Main.c compiled on 172.17.0.2 in 0.0063s, rate 2274kB/s
distcc[13039] (dcc_unlock) release lock fd3
distcc[13039] ERROR: compile /home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles/Boot/Main.c on 172.17.0.2/1 failed
distcc[13039] (dcc_build_somewhere) Warning: remote compilation of '/home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles/Boot/Main.c' failed, retrying locally
distcc[13039] (dcc_mark_timefile) mark /home/user/.distcc/lock/backoff_tcp_172.17.0.2_3632_0
distcc[13039] Warning: failed to distribute /home/user/sandbox/distcc-makefiles/Boot/Main.c to 172.17.0.2/1, running locally instead
```

where, to my understanding, *SECTION A* finds the remote server, *SECTION B* opens a connection to the server, *SECTION C* send the command to run in the server (includes the compile options and the file to compile), *SECTION D* fetches the result, and *SECTION E* analizes the result and decides what to do next. As you might see, this is the error:

```
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_string) send string '@_out/Release/Boot/Main.o.via'
distcc[13039] (dcc_x_token_int) send ARGV00000002
```

Answer (score 1):

To see output of compile error, define these environment above:

```
export DISTCC_VERBOSE=1
export DISTCC_SAVE_TEMPS=1
export DISTCC_FALLBACK=0
```

see also `man distcc` or https://linux.die.net/man/1/distcc

Answer (score 0):

current distcc maintainer,

I highly recommend using `MASQUERADE` as documented in the distcc man page.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, although that was not the problem. If interested I posted an answer explaining the issue. I am not sure if that is an expected behavior or a bug.

Comment: Oh yes, that feature cannot possibly work, as it would require changing the protocol. If you want to submit a patch that would reject the problematic invocations earlier, I would be happy to review the patch. https://github.com/distcc/distcc